# Chat clients (which will allow to encode music and vowel length and consonant characteristics)

Tags: gratis, android, graphs, accessibility, speech-synthesis

Suppose a person cannot speak [/and ;\ wants to send a voiced message to someone.

The current granularity of selecting a voice |may not be sufficient.

Two approaches could exist:

A. For people that can see and also for blind people (just use voice to activate the special features (using special voice keywords), for each syllable can be underscored by a note symbol chosen (just bracket the syllable and place a note as a subscript, each letter can also be given a phoneme type (thrilled r or rolled r, easy h, harsh h, or cough h, (or other experimental sounds)), machine sounds for letters as subscripts as well (nice, medium, and worse - sounds, perhaps only pronouncable by a machine but linguistically nice-sounding). Also select a vowel length via a subscript.

B. Let the computer sound the word in a variety of possible ways, and choose from the list. Good for people that can hear, and also for blind people who can say "ok" or NEXT, at each step, but not good for people who can'tspeak or could have a speech disorder.

C. This method is not exclusive of A and B, but could be used in conjunction:

Place the letters along the time axis, spaced on the time axis as you like. You can also fix them if you cannot move arms, mouth, but only move your eyes. With your eyes. Blink, stare at keyboard, stare at letter, blink to select, user interface switches to graph, stare at time axis (a special medium-gray circle moves slowly left or right, as you stir left or right, blink to fix letter along time axis (you will need a large screen interface here, perhaps an Android TV monitor). Quickly blink five times to proceed to y-axis. Again, you will place your dark-gray circles along t-axis, then quintuple-blink (more then 5 blinks will act as 5), move each vertically to control tone (in the same way as on x-axis). Right-eye blink: go back. Left-eye blink: go forward. Long-blink: quickly jump forward along action and subaction tree. Double long-blink: SOUND IT. THREE CONSECUTIVE long-blinks: SEND.

Comment: What you describe makes me think you rather want a complex sound studio. What's wrong with simple TTS (text-to-speech) for a simple audio message -- or sending a text message and have the recipient decide? Apart from that: what does it has to do with vector-graphics and graphs -- and what OS should it run on?

Comment: This is for people that cannot speak. They want to send a message to someone which reflects their mood and current state of being at the present moment. SMS and text do not completely cater to this, not even with smileys. Imagine wanting to send a message in a way that you will not want the receiving party to rrinterpret it wrongly, and want no chance of this hapoening. In that case you woukd want an android app to edit the TTS outout, and then send the edited TTS output. This is for those many times a speechless person finds themselves wanting to add some voice flavor to their multimedia msg.

Comment: ...while doing it all from their phone.

Comment: Thanks for the background, Jack! I've replaced the `vector-graphics` tag by `android` then. I've never heard of such an Android app unfortunately, so I only can wish you good luck!

Comment: Thanks, @Izzy. I wilk be on the watchout for any of these. In the meantime, if you come actoss anything related (or interesting) please let me know.